# How to interpret the output of Weka MultilayerPerceptron?

Tags: neural-network, weka

I have a Multilayer Perceptron model in Weka and I want to extract knowledge from this output:

```
=== Classifier model (full training set) ===
...
Sigmoid Node 19
    Inputs    Weights
    Threshold    -0.1952207078426809
    Attrib Age    6.055214343595766
    Attrib Gender=Female    1.9806393961914877
    Attrib Polyuria=Yes    2.092522712544858
    Attrib Polydipsia=No    -1.2458204564691266
    Attrib sudden weight loss=Yes    0.4185898280097185
    Attrib weakness=No    -0.8314652455975647
    Attrib Polyphagia=Yes    -0.48400540426846483
    Attrib Genital thrush=Yes    -0.2226565451203396
    Attrib visual blurring=Yes    3.0186785501154456
    Attrib Itching=No    1.9350277038164228
    Attrib Irritability=Yes    -1.3543816020735406
    Attrib delayed healing=No    1.862432846595033
    Attrib partial paresis=Yes    1.0250701513525546
    Attrib muscle stiffness=No    2.0216597800998932
    Attrib Alopecia=No    0.5984702263543803
    Attrib Obesity=No    -1.704440363167018
Class Positive
    Input
    Node 0
Class Negative
    Input
    Node 1
```

How can I interpret this output (the nodes and the weights)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might have to dig into the source itself to understand how the output relates to the calculations underneath the hood. Here is a link to the [toString()](https://github.com/Waikato/weka-trunk/blob/7b19faa2980f9a7f4c3de0f10f1e75c8f1cb52b1/weka/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/functions/MultilayerPerceptron.java#L2570) method of the MultilayerPerceptron classifier that generated this output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems hard to understand the whole method. I would like to know: what sigmoid node it's the most important? Are negative weights worst than positive weights?

Comment: Looking at the [outputValue()](https://github.com/Waikato/weka-trunk/blob/7b19faa2980f9a7f4c3de0f10f1e75c8f1cb52b1/weka/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/functions/neural/SigmoidUnit.java#L44) method of the SigmoidUnit class, it looks that way. But I'm not familiar with that code base, so I might be wrong.